# How to add vertical stretchable glue to tables?

Tags: tables, spacing, glue

Is it possible to add stretchable vertical glue to rows of a `tabular` (I actually use `tabularx`) environment?

I've looked at [`tabularht`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularht), but if I have understood right, this allows me to specify a total height for a table, whereas, I would prefer to add stretchable space to each row using `\\[…]` notation.

I don't have vertical lines in my tables.

I'd like the left and right columns to look roughly the same in the following example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\newlength{\sep}\setlength{\sep}{2cm plus 5cm minus 1cm}
\flushbottom
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
One\vspace{\sep}

Two\vspace{\sep}

\break

\begin{tabular}{l}
  One\\[\sep]
  Two\\[\sep]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: short answer no, longer answer you could in principle let tex construct the table into a box and then disassemble the box and re-assembe the rows inserting glue as needed.