# How to fit a table to textheight by automatically adjusting arraystretch

Tags: tables, resize, textheight

I am preparing the academic calendar for my institution. It typically looks like the following:
[image]

As you can see, I need to create 24 tables like this. I will create `tabular` to fit the data. Each table will contain around 28 - 36 rows. What I am looking here for is to be able to modify the `\arraystretch` component *automatically* so that the total table height is same as the `\textheight`. I *do not want* to use the `resizebox` or `adjustbox` as it will mess with the font size in each page. The following MWE contains the information about the font and page sizes, and is motivated from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648125/162028) to my [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/648098/162028) posted earlier.

```
\documentclass[9pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=108mm, paperheight=140mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, foot=2.5mm, head=2.5mm, showframe, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\color{cyan}\leftmark~|~\lastrightmark~|~Academic Calendar 2022-23}
\fancyhead[RO]{\color{cyan}Academic Calendar 2022-23~|~\lastrightmark~|~\leftmark}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\parindent0pt
\parskip0pt
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\Rownum{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\ifnum\value{magicrownumbers}<10 0\fi\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\preto\table{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
\preto\tabular{\setcounter{magicrownumbers}{0}}
%
%
%
\newcount\myjdate
\newcount\myweekday
\newcounter{tmpmyjdate}
\newcounter{tmpmyweekday}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\def\wday#1{%
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\myjdate}%
\setcounter{tmpmyjdate}{\the\myjdate}%
\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
\setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
\nwday%
}
\def\nwday{%
\ifcase\value{tmpmyweekday} Mon\or Tue\or Wen\or Thu\or Fri\or Sat\or Sun\fi\relax%
\stepcounter{tmpmyjdate}\relax%
\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
\setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\color{cyan}Academic Calendar\\2022-23}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \newpage
\section{July}
\subsection{Sonada}
    \begin{center}
    \def\arraystretch{1}% <== need to adjust this automatically
        \begin{tabular}{rlll}
            \Rownum.    & \wday{2022-07-01} & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \newpage
\subsection{Siliguri}
%
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{rlll}
            \Rownum.    & \wday{2022-07-01} & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\ 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
%
\end{document}
```

The MWE is agreeably a little long to provide more information as to avoid any possible clash with the commands or packages.

Comment: Looks like there isn't, [spacing - How to add vertical stretchable glue to tables? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449480/how-to-add-vertical-stretchable-glue-to-tables)

Comment: Here is a similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610595/table-with-header-row-of-normal-height-remaining-rows-fill-page-vertically-tab/610598#610598) with a solution using `tabularray` package.

Comment: @L.J.R. Can you please post a full solution here? I tried implementing your suggestion, couldn't produce the output properly. See [this](https://www.overleaf.com/read/kthtkdqynrmw).

Comment: I have added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `tabularray` package and three remarks:

1. the `\textheight` is so small that the page can not include 28 rows, so you need to decrease document font size first.
2. there are some vertical shift in the second page, which is caused by the `\section` commnad, so you need to adjust it.
3. the `tabularray.sty` in your Overleaf project is a little old, please download the latest one (version 2022B) from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray).

```
\documentclass[9pt, twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=108mm, paperheight=140mm, top=15mm, bottom=15mm, left=15mm, right=15mm, foot=2.5mm, head=2.5mm, showframe, marginparsep=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{\@gobble}
\makeatother
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{-\baselineskip}{*0}

\usepackage{fancyhdr, extramarks}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\color{cyan}\leftmark~|~\lastrightmark~|~Academic Calendar 2022-23}
\fancyhead[RO]{\color{cyan}Academic Calendar 2022-23~|~\lastrightmark~|~\leftmark}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{ragged2e}
\parindent0pt
\parskip0pt

\selectcolormodel{natural}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\SetTblrInner[tblr]{rowsep=0pt,stretch=0}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\Rownum{\ifnum\value{rownum}<10 0\fi\arabic{rownum}}
\newcommand\calcrowht{%
  \dimexpr
    (
      \textheight
       %- 0.4pt * ( \value{rowcount} + 1) % hrule sizes
    ) / \value{rowcount}
  \relax
}

\newcount\myjdate
\newcount\myweekday
\newcounter{tmpmyjdate}
\newcounter{tmpmyweekday}
\usepackage{pgfcalendar}
\def\wday#1{%
\pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1}{\myjdate}%
\setcounter{tmpmyjdate}{\the\myjdate}%
\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
\setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
\nwday%
}
\def\nwday{%
\ifcase\value{tmpmyweekday}Mon\or Tue\or Wen\or Thu\or Fri\or Sat\or Sun\fi\relax%
\stepcounter{tmpmyjdate}\relax%
\pgfcalendarjuliantoweekday{\thetmpmyjdate}{\myweekday}%
\setcounter{tmpmyweekday}{\the\myweekday}%
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \vspace*{\fill}
    \begin{center}
        {\Large\color{cyan}Academic Calendar\\2022-23}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \newpage
\section{July}%
\subsection{Sonada}%
       \begin{tblr}[t]{colspec={rlll},rows={ht=\calcrowht},row{even}={gray9},row{odd}={azure9}}
            \Rownum.    & \wday{2022-07-01} & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
%            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content
        \end{tblr}
    \newpage
\subsection{Siliguri}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={rlll},rows={ht=\calcrowht},row{even}={gray9},row{odd}={azure9}}
            \Rownum.    & \wday{2022-07-01} & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
            \Rownum.    & \nwday & Type & Content\\
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and comments. May I ask the last favour please! Can you please fix the `columnwidth`s in the following way: First and second columns will be as they appear in the above code. The longest word in the third column will be "Class". The fourth column will have the rest of the spaces and the contents in that column should wrap if needed. The entire width of the table will be same as `\textwidth`. Thank you.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul Sorry, I can do it if the text wrap.

Comment: Okay. I guess in that case, I have to manually wrap the text into the next line. Thanks for your help so far.